# How to register existing instances in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, microsoft-extensions-di

I am migrating my .NET applications Dependency Injection framework from `Unity Container` to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

Now I did not find a way to register an already existing instance of an interface to the serviceCollection. In Unity this was possible like this:

```
_unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IInterface>(myObject);
```

In `IServiceCollection` I found only `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped`, `AddTransient` all of which only take types.

(I know doing this might be bad practice in the first place, but it is unfortunately not under my control.)

Comment: AddSingleton should have an overload taking an instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an overload for `AddSingleton<T>` that accepts the implementation instance, e.g.:

```
services.AddSingleton<IInterface>(myObject);
```

In addition, there are overloads for `AddScoped<T>` and `AddTransient<T>` that accept a factory function as parameter. So you could register your interface like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IInterface>((prov) => myObject);    
services.AddTransient<IInterface>((prov) => myObject);
```

However, the latter misses the point of having an instance per scope or a transient instance if you always return the same instance - this is better matched with a singleton registration. This explains why there is a special overload for `AddSingleton<T>` in contrast to `AddScoped<T>` or `AddTransient<T>`.